# Is it possible to use express.js to build rest api in frontend?

Tags: mysql, rest, express, frontend, backend

the plan is to build the web app with react.js and also build the backend using express.js specfically using rest api to connec to mySQL database....the problem is

1. for authentication, my supervisor doesnt want me to store password anywhere, instead he suggested me to build an authentication using the usename and password that we use to connect to mySQL database. For example, when i try to make a connection with mysqlCreateConnection method, theres a section where i have to fill out the ip address and username and password. the problem is if i do this, when the user logs out, the connection between backend and database will disconnect......

is it possible to use mySQL createconnection in the front end? so whenever the user logs in it will connect to the database directly from the frontend? once the connection is created, then use backend rest api? if this works i assume the rest api has to be hosted with the same url as the frontend, since we made the connection to mySQL database in the frontend.......but again if we do this, doesnt it defeat the purpose of backend? meaning anyone can login to the frontend and change whatever they want to the backend?

so the result will be like

1. within the frontend. user logs in using mySQL workbench username and password, then that username and password is going to fill out the mysql createconnection method(this method is written in the frontend). which will then try to connect to the database.
2. user logs in successfull
3. user fills out a form about a product and clicks on submit and this data is send to our rest api, and mySQL database adds the data in.

Comment: are you trying to make something like [this](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)?

Comment: @The_flash no this is not what we are trying to do......we are trying to build an auth system without storing password or username and specifically we want to build a auth system base off the account we created in mySQL workbench, when connection is succesfull, then we log the user in.

Comment: ok , you'd still need back-end to connect to the db. Upon every login request you'd need to authenticate with the db. From there I suggest you send encrypted versions of the pwd and username back to react in a JWT to make further requests. This is all VERY bad practice btw.

Answer (score 0):

[here are examples of router-token and router-session within the app if you are at express.js.](https://github.com/mensenvau/)

**db.js**

```
const mysql = require("mysql2")
const config = require("../../config/config.json").DB

module.exports = mysql.createPool({
    host: config.host,
    user: config.username,
    password: config.password,
    database: config.database,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 100,
    queueLimit: 0,
    multipleStatements: true
})
```

**db.fun.js**

```
const db = require("./db").promise()

let query = async(sql, data) => {
    try {
        let d = await db.query(sql, data);
        return d[0];
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`EDB: ./app/database/db.fun.js 8rows \n${err}`);
        return { err: 1, errdata: err };
    }
}

module.exports = {
    query: query
}
```

**import query**

```
(async function(){

    const { query } = require("../database/db.fun");
    let user = await query("SELECT * FROM users",[]);
     
    console.log(user)

})();
```